# Magento 2 - Allow only to post product reviews by customer who purchased that particular product

Tags: product, magento2.2, product-review

I do not want the customers/guest to let post reviews who did not make a purchase of that product.

- for guest users I disable - "Allow guest to write reviews"
- for customers/logged in users - how to add a condition to check customer has purchased a particular product at least once?

Those who have purchased a particular product that should be able to post review from a product page.

Answer (score 2):

As you have wanted to show review form only login customer who has purchased that product.

Then you have to stop render of the block `Magento\Review\Block\Form`  on sales order item collection.

First, you have to create a plugin on `toHtml()` at  `Magento\Review\Block\Form` and use aroundToHtml() **method** to stop html render.

### Plugin Class

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Review\Block;


class FormPlugin {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
            ) {

        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }
    public function aroundToHtml(
        \Magento\Review\Block\Form $subject,
        \Closure $proceed       
    )
    {
        $product = $subject->getProductInfo();
        $itemCollection = $this->itemCollectionFactory->create();
        $itemCollection->addFieldToSelect('product_id')->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product->getId());
        if($itemCollection->count() >0 ){
//Make string to object.
          return $proceed();  

        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a customer views the product, we will check all orders of that customer if the current product exists in any orders, then show the review form and if not show a message.

We will use the preference to override the method named _construct() in the class named \Magento\Review\Block\Form
That is the method we will override. We will update the template path to the new template if the customer has not purchased that product yet.

Let's done this functionality you need to follow steps by step:

**Step 1: Declaring the new module called Magento_ProductReviewForm**

- Create the namespace Magento in the path app\code
- Create the module named ProductReviewForm in the path app\code\Magento
- Create the file named registration.php in the path app\code\Magento\ProductReviewForm
- Create the file named module.xml in the path app\code\Magento\ProductReviewForm\etc

End of step #1, I have completed the codes to create the new module called Magento_ProductReviewForm.

**Step 2: Override the class named \Magento\Review\Block\Form**

- Create the new file named di.xml in the path app\code\Magento\ProductReviewForm\etc\frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Form" type="Magento\ProductReviewForm\Override\Review\Block\Form" />
</config>
```

- Create the new file named Form.php in the path app\code\Magento\ProductReviewForm\Override\Review\Block

```
<?php

namespace Magento\ProductReviewForm\Override\Review\Block;

class Form extends \Magento\Review\Block\Form
{
    /**
     * Initialize review form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        // If the current product doesn't exist in the orders of the current customer
        if (!$this->getAlreadyPurchasedProduct()) {
            $this->setTemplate('Magento_ProductReviewForm::review/form.phtml');
        } else {
            $this->setTemplate('Magento_Review::form.phtml');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the current customer purchased the current product.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function getAlreadyPurchasedProduct()
    {
        // If is Guest then hide the review form
        if (!$this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->getProductInfo();
            $orders = $this->getCustomerOrders();
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                // Get all visible items in the order
                /** @var $items \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface[] **/
                $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
                // Loop all items
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    // Check whether the current product exist in the order.
                    if ($item->getProductId() == $product->getId()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the orders of the current customer. Only get orders are completed
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order[]
     */
    private function getCustomerOrders()
    {
        $order = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory::class);
        $orderCollection = $order->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id', $this->getCustomerId()
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'status', \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE
        );
        return $orderCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Returns customer id from session
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function getCustomerId()
    {
        $customerSession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory::class);
        return $customerSession->create()->getId();
    }
}
```

- Create the new file named form.phtml in the path app\code\Magento\ProductReviewForm\view\frontend\templates\review

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\ProductReviewForm\Override\Review\Block\Form **/ ?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Your Own Review')) ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
    <div class="message info notpurchased" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You can not add the review on this product as you have not purchased this product yet.')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 3: Test and See the results**

```
Run the following command lines:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```